# RxJava- MissingBackpressureException on my Operator?

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming

I implemented my own customer Operator called `DoCountOperator`, which supports custom `Observable` operators I created like `doOnNextCount()`, `doOnErrorCount()`, and `doOnCompletedCount()` count. It allows creating a side-effect for these events and do something with the emission count at those events. For example, `doOnCompletedCount()` allows you to create a side effect with the full emission count after the `onCompleted()` event.

I am running into a `MissingBackpressureException`problem for a large number of emissions though, and my stack trace gives mention to my operator. Here is the `Operator`...

```
final class DoCountOperator<T> implements Observable.Operator<T,T> {

    interface CountObserver {
        void onNext(int emissionCount);
        void onError(int emissionCount);
        void onCompleted(int emissionCount);
    }

    private final DoCountOperator.CountObserver doObserver;

    DoCountOperator(DoCountOperator.CountObserver doObserver) {
        this.doObserver = doObserver;
    }

    @Override
    public Subscriber<? super T> call(Subscriber<? super T> child) {
        return new Subscriber<T>() {
            private int count = 0;
            private boolean done = false;

            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {
                if (done) {
                    return;
                }
                try {
                    doObserver.onCompleted(count);
                }catch (Throwable throwable) {
                    //Exceptions.throwIfFatal(throwable);
                    onError(throwable);
                }

                done = true;
                child.onCompleted();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
                if (done) {
                    return;
                }
                try {
                    doObserver.onError(count);
                } catch (Throwable throwable1) {
                    throwable1.printStackTrace();
                }
                child.onError(throwable);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(T t) {
                if (done) {
                    return;
                }
                try {
                    doObserver.onNext(++count);
                }catch (Throwable throwable) {
                    Exceptions.throwIfFatal(throwable);
                }
                child.onNext(t);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

And here is how `doOnCompletedCount()` uses it. I'm getting an error when I emit something like 50,000 to 90,000 emitted items.

```
public static <T> Observable.Operator<T,T> doOnCompletedCount(final IntConsumer countAction) {
        return new DoCountOperator<>(new DoCountOperator.CountObserver() {
            @Override
            public void onNext(int emissionCount) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(int emissionCount) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCompleted(int emissionCount) {
                countAction.accept(emissionCount);
            }
        });
    }
```

I cannot think of how this operator might be overwhelmed by backpressure, but perhaps it is failing to communicate a backpressure problem across the chain? What exactly am I doing wrong? Here is the stack trace...

```
rx.exceptions.MissingBackpressureException
                at rx.internal.util.RxRingBuffer.onNext(RxRingBuffer.java:352)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.queueScalar(OperatorMerge.java:346)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.tryEmit(OperatorMerge.java:329)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$InnerSubscriber.onNext(OperatorMerge.java:804)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorScan$2.onNext(OperatorScan.java:117)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMap$1.onNext(OperatorMap.java:54)
                at com.swa.rm.common.rx.DoCountOperator$1.onNext(DoCountOperator.java:66)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorFinally$1.onNext(OperatorFinally.java:48)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorDoOnEach$1.onNext(OperatorDoOnEach.java:85)
                at rx.observers.SerializedObserver.onNext(SerializedObserver.java:95)
                at rx.observers.SerializedSubscriber.onNext(SerializedSubscriber.java:95)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorConcat$ConcatInnerSubscriber.onNext(OperatorConcat.java:199)
                at com.swa.rm.common.rx.RxOperators$1.onNext(RxOperators.java:49)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMap$1.onNext(OperatorMap.java:54)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMap$1.onNext(OperatorMap.java:54)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorFinally$1.onNext(OperatorFinally.java:48)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorDoOnEach$1.onNext(OperatorDoOnEach.java:85)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.emitScalar(OperatorMerge.java:365)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.tryEmit(OperatorMerge.java:327)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$InnerSubscriber.onNext(OperatorMerge.java:804)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.emitScalar(OperatorMerge.java:365)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.tryEmit(OperatorMerge.java:327)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$InnerSubscriber.onNext(OperatorMerge.java:804)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn$1$1$1.onNext(OperatorSubscribeOn.java:76)
                at rx.internal.operators.NotificationLite.accept(NotificationLite.java:150)
                at rx.internal.operators.CachedObservable$ReplayProducer.replay(CachedObservable.java:404)
                at rx.internal.operators.CachedObservable$CacheState.dispatch(CachedObservable.java:220)
                at rx.internal.operators.CachedObservable$CacheState.onNext(CachedObservable.java:191)
                at rx.internal.operators.CachedObservable$CacheState$1.onNext(CachedObservable.java:171)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.emitScalar(OperatorMerge.java:365)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.tryEmit(OperatorMerge.java:327)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$InnerSubscriber.onNext(OperatorMerge.java:804)
                at rx.observers.SerializedObserver.onNext(SerializedObserver.java:95)
                at rx.observers.SerializedSubscriber.onNext(SerializedSubscriber.java:95)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorConcat$ConcatInnerSubscriber.onNext(OperatorConcat.java:199)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorDoOnEach$1.onNext(OperatorDoOnEach.java:85)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMap$1.onNext(OperatorMap.java:54)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorTake$1.onNext(OperatorTake.java:73)
                at rx.observers.SerializedObserver.onNext(SerializedObserver.java:95)
                at rx.observers.SerializedSubscriber.onNext(SerializedSubscriber.java:95)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorConcat$ConcatInnerSubscriber.onNext(OperatorConcat.java:199)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMap$1.onNext(OperatorMap.java:54)
                at rx.observers.SerializedObserver.onNext(SerializedObserver.java:95)
                at rx.observers.SerializedSubscriber.onNext(SerializedSubscriber.java:95)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorConcat$ConcatInnerSubscriber.onNext(OperatorConcat.java:199)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorFilter$1.onNext(OperatorFilter.java:54)
                at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$1.call(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:46)
                at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$1.call(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:35)
                at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162)
                at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154)
                at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:8098)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorConcat$ConcatSubscriber.subscribeNext(OperatorConcat.java:172)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorConcat$ConcatSubscriber.onNext(OperatorConcat.java:136)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorConcat$ConcatSubscriber.onNext(OperatorConcat.java:79)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMap$1.onNext(OperatorMap.java:54)
                at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$1.call(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:46)
                at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$1.call(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:35)
                at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162)
                at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154)
                at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162)
                at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154)
                at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162)
                at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154)
                at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:8098)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorConcat$ConcatSubscriber.subscribeNext(OperatorConcat.java:172)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorConcat$ConcatSubscriber.onNext(OperatorConcat.java:136)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorConcat$ConcatSubscriber.onNext(OperatorConcat.java:79)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMap$1.onNext(OperatorMap.java:54)
                at rx.observers.SerializedObserver.onNext(SerializedObserver.java:95)
                at rx.observers.SerializedSubscriber.onNext(SerializedSubscriber.java:95)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorConcat$ConcatInnerSubscriber.onNext(OperatorConcat.java:199)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMap$1.onNext(OperatorMap.java:54)
                at rx.observers.SerializedObserver.onNext(SerializedObserver.java:95)
                at rx.observers.SerializedSubscriber.onNext(SerializedSubscriber.java:95)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorConcat$ConcatInnerSubscriber.onNext(OperatorConcat.java:199)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorFilter$1.onNext(OperatorFilter.java:54)
                at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$1.call(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:46)
                at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$1.call(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:35)
                at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162)
                at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154)
                at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:8098)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorConcat$ConcatSubscriber.subscribeNext(OperatorConcat.java:172)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorConcat$ConcatSubscriber.onNext(OperatorConcat.java:136)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorConcat$ConcatSubscriber.onNext(OperatorConcat.java:79)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMap$1.onNext(OperatorMap.java:54)
                at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$1.call(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:46)
                at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$1.call(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:35)
                at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162)
                at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154)
                at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162)
                at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154)
                at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162)
                at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154)
                at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:8098)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorConcat$ConcatSubscriber.subscribeNext(OperatorConcat.java:172)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorConcat$ConcatSubscriber.onNext(OperatorConcat.java:136)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorConcat$ConcatSubscriber.onNext(OperatorConcat.java:79)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMap$1.onNext(OperatorMap.java:54)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorFilter$1.onNext(OperatorFilter.java:54)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.emitScalar(OperatorMerge.java:365)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.tryEmit(OperatorMerge.java:327)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$InnerSubscriber.onNext(OperatorMerge.java:804)
                at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeFromIterable$IterableProducer.slowpath(OnSubscribeFromIterable.java:97)
                at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeFromIterable$IterableProducer.request(OnSubscribeFromIterable.java:73)
                at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:211)
                at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeFromIterable.call(OnSubscribeFromIterable.java:49)
                at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeFromIterable.call(OnSubscribeFromIterable.java:32)
                at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:8098)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.onNext(OperatorMerge.java:232)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.onNext(OperatorMerge.java:142)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMap$1.onNext(OperatorMap.java:54)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMap$1.onNext(OperatorMap.java:54)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMap$1.onNext(OperatorMap.java:54)
                at rx.internal.operators.NotificationLite.accept(NotificationLite.java:150)
                at rx.internal.operators.CachedObservable$ReplayProducer.replay(CachedObservable.java:404)
                at rx.internal.operators.CachedObservable$ReplayProducer.request(CachedObservable.java:304)
                at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:211)
                at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:205)
                at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:205)
                at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:205)
                at rx.internal.operators.CachedObservable$CachedSubscribe.call(CachedObservable.java:244)
                at rx.internal.operators.CachedObservable$CachedSubscribe.call(CachedObservable.java:230)
                at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162)
                at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154)
                at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162)
                at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154)
                at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162)
                at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154)
                at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162)
                at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154)
                at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162)
                at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154)
                at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162)
                at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154)
                at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162)
                at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154)
                at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162)
                at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154)
                at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162)
                at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154)
                at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162)
                at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154)
                at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162)
                at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154)
                at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162)
                at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154)
                at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:8098)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorConcat$ConcatSubscriber.subscribeNext(OperatorConcat.java:172)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorConcat$ConcatSubscriber.onNext(OperatorConcat.java:136)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorConcat$ConcatSubscriber.onNext(OperatorConcat.java:79)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMap$1.onNext(OperatorMap.java:54)
                at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeFromIterable$IterableProducer.slowpath(OnSubscribeFromIterable.java:97)
                at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeFromIterable$IterableProducer.request(OnSubscribeFromIterable.java:73)
                at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:211)
                at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:205)
                at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeFromIterable.call(OnSubscribeFromIterable.java:49)
                at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeFromIterable.call(OnSubscribeFromIterable.java:32)
                at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162)
                at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154)
                at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162)
                at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154)
                at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:8098)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.onNext(OperatorMerge.java:232)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.onNext(OperatorMerge.java:142)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMap$1.onNext(OperatorMap.java:54)
                at rx.internal.operators.NotificationLite.accept(NotificationLite.java:150)
                at rx.internal.operators.CachedObservable$ReplayProducer.replay(CachedObservable.java:404)
                at rx.internal.operators.CachedObservable$CacheState.dispatch(CachedObservable.java:220)
                at rx.internal.operators.CachedObservable$CacheState.onNext(CachedObservable.java:191)
                at rx.internal.operators.CachedObservable$CacheState$1.onNext(CachedObservable.java:171)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.emitScalar(OperatorMerge.java:365)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.tryEmit(OperatorMerge.java:327)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$InnerSubscriber.onNext(OperatorMerge.java:804)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMap$1.onNext(OperatorMap.java:54)
                at rx.internal.producers.SingleDelayedProducer.emit(SingleDelayedProducer.java:102)
                at rx.internal.producers.SingleDelayedProducer.setValue(SingleDelayedProducer.java:85)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorToObservableSortedList$2.onCompleted(OperatorToObservableSortedList.java:82)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMap$1.onCompleted(OperatorMap.java:43)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorGroupBy$GroupBySubscriber$2$2.onCompleted(OperatorGroupBy.java:264)
                at rx.observers.Subscribers$5.onCompleted(Subscribers.java:220)
                at rx.internal.operators.BufferUntilSubscriber.onCompleted(BufferUntilSubscriber.java:155)
                at rx.internal.operators.NotificationLite.accept(NotificationLite.java:140)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorGroupBy$GroupBySubscriber.emitItem(OperatorGroupBy.java:339)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorGroupBy$GroupBySubscriber.onCompleted(OperatorGroupBy.java:161)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.emitLoop(OperatorMerge.java:614)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.emit(OperatorMerge.java:526)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.onCompleted(OperatorMerge.java:255)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMap$1.onCompleted(OperatorMap.java:43)
                at rx.internal.operators.NotificationLite.accept(NotificationLite.java:140)
                at rx.internal.operators.CachedObservable$ReplayProducer.replay(CachedObservable.java:404)
                at rx.internal.operators.CachedObservable$CacheState.dispatch(CachedObservable.java:220)
                at rx.internal.operators.CachedObservable$CacheState.onCompleted(CachedObservable.java:211)
                at rx.internal.operators.CachedObservable$CacheState$1.onCompleted(CachedObservable.java:179)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.emitLoop(OperatorMerge.java:614)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.emit(OperatorMerge.java:526)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.onCompleted(OperatorMerge.java:255)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMap$1.onCompleted(OperatorMap.java:43)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.emitLoop(OperatorMerge.java:614)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.emit(OperatorMerge.java:526)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.onCompleted(OperatorMerge.java:255)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMap$1.onCompleted(OperatorMap.java:43)
                at rx.internal.operators.NotificationLite.accept(NotificationLite.java:140)
                at rx.internal.operators.CachedObservable$ReplayProducer.replay(CachedObservable.java:404)
                at rx.internal.operators.CachedObservable$CacheState.dispatch(CachedObservable.java:220)
                at rx.internal.operators.CachedObservable$CacheState.onCompleted(CachedObservable.java:211)
                at rx.internal.operators.CachedObservable$CacheState$1.onCompleted(CachedObservable.java:179)
                at rx.observers.SerializedObserver.onCompleted(SerializedObserver.java:183)
                at rx.observers.SerializedSubscriber.onCompleted(SerializedSubscriber.java:65)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorConcat$ConcatSubscriber.subscribeNext(OperatorConcat.java:167)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorConcat$ConcatSubscriber.onCompleted(OperatorConcat.java:150)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMap$1.onCompleted(OperatorMap.java:43)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorBufferWithSize$1.onCompleted(OperatorBufferWithSize.java:126)
                at rx.observers.SerializedObserver.onCompleted(SerializedObserver.java:183)
                at rx.observers.SerializedSubscriber.onCompleted(SerializedSubscriber.java:65)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorConcat$ConcatSubscriber.subscribeNext(OperatorConcat.java:167)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorConcat$ConcatSubscriber.onCompleted(OperatorConcat.java:150)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMap$1.onCompleted(OperatorMap.java:43)
                at rx.observers.SerializedObserver.onCompleted(SerializedObserver.java:183)
                at rx.observers.SerializedSubscriber.onCompleted(SerializedSubscriber.java:65)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorConcat$ConcatSubscriber.subscribeNext(OperatorConcat.java:167)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorConcat$ConcatSubscriber.onCompleted(OperatorConcat.java:150)
                at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeFromIterable$IterableProducer.slowpath(OnSubscribeFromIterable.java:101)
                at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeFromIterable$IterableProducer.request(OnSubscribeFromIterable.java:73)
                at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:211)
                at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeFromIterable.call(OnSubscribeFromIterable.java:49)
                at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeFromIterable.call(OnSubscribeFromIterable.java:32)
                at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162)
                at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154)
                at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162)
                at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154)
                at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162)
                at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154)
                at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162)
                at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154)
                at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162)
                at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154)
                at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162)
                at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154)
                at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:8098)
                at rx.internal.operators.CachedObservable$CacheState.connect(CachedObservable.java:183)
                at rx.internal.operators.CachedObservable$CachedSubscribe.call(CachedObservable.java:248)
                at rx.internal.operators.CachedObservable$CachedSubscribe.call(CachedObservable.java:230)
                at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162)
                at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154)
                at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162)
                at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154)
                at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162)
                at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154)
                at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162)
                at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154)
                at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:8098)
                at rx.internal.operators.CachedObservable$CacheState.connect(CachedObservable.java:183)
                at rx.internal.operators.CachedObservable$CachedSubscribe.call(CachedObservable.java:248)
                at rx.internal.operators.CachedObservable$CachedSubscribe.call(CachedObservable.java:230)
                at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162)
                at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154)
                at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162)
                at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154)
                at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162)
                at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154)
                at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162)
                at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154)
                at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162)
                at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154)
                at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:8098)
                at rx.internal.operators.CachedObservable$CacheState.connect(CachedObservable.java:183)
                at rx.internal.operators.CachedObservable$CachedSubscribe.call(CachedObservable.java:248)
                at rx.internal.operators.CachedObservable$CachedSubscribe.call(CachedObservable.java:230)
                at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162)
                at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154)
                at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162)
                at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154)
                at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:8098)
                at rx.internal.operators.CachedObservable$CacheState.connect(CachedObservable.java:183)
                at rx.internal.operators.CachedObservable$CachedSubscribe.call(CachedObservable.java:248)
                at rx.internal.operators.CachedObservable$CachedSubscribe.call(CachedObservable.java:230)
                at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:8098)
                at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn$1$1.call(OperatorSubscribeOn.java:62)
                at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55)
                at rx.schedulers.ExecutorScheduler$ExecutorSchedulerWorker.run(ExecutorScheduler.java:98)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Reading an article on David Karnok's blog. This probably contains the answer. http://akarnokd.blogspot.hu/2015/05/pitfalls-of-operator-implementations_14.html

Comment: See pitfall #1 in my blog http://akarnokd.blogspot.hu/2015/05/pitfalls-of-operator-implementations.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to link the downstream Subscriber's unsubscription and backpressure "channels" in your code. You need something like this:

```
final class DoCountOperator<T> implements Observable.Operator<T,T> {

    interface CountObserver {
        void onNext(int emissionCount);
        void onError(int emissionCount);
        void onCompleted(int emissionCount);
    }

    private final DoCountOperator.CountObserver doObserver;

    DoCountOperator(DoCountOperator.CountObserver doObserver) {
        this.doObserver = doObserver;
    }

    @Override
    public Subscriber<? super T> call(Subscriber<? super T> child) {
        Subscriber<T> parent = new Subscriber<T>() {
            private int count = 0;
            private boolean done = false;

            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {
                if (done) {
                    return;
                }
                try {
                    doObserver.onCompleted(count);
                }catch (Throwable throwable) {
                    //Exceptions.throwIfFatal(throwable);
                    onError(throwable);
                }

                done = true;
                child.onCompleted();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
                if (done) {
                    return;
                }
                try {
                    doObserver.onError(count);
                } catch (Throwable throwable1) {
                    throwable1.printStackTrace();
                }
                child.onError(throwable);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(T t) {
                if (done) {
                    return;
                }
                try {
                    doObserver.onNext(++count);
                }catch (Throwable throwable) {
                    Exceptions.throwIfFatal(throwable);
                }
                child.onNext(t);
            }

            @Override
            public void setProducer(Producer p) {
                child.setProducer(p);
            }
        };

        child.add(parent);

        return parent;
    }
}
```

So instead of returning the custom Subscriber on call(), you put it into a local variable and call `child.add(parent)` thus establishing the unsubscription chain. For the backpressure to work, the best is to override `setProducer` in the custom Subscriber and simply call `child.setProducer` with the received `Producer` instance.

Comment: I was pretty sure I would have to do something with `setProducer()` although I was unsure what exactly. Tricky. If I'm going to create my own operators I probably should set aside some time to read your articles and get it right.